# Confusion on Importing & Running files in an Eclipse IDE Java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an assignment which requires importing a group of files into a Java project in Eclipse IDE (consisting of .java and a .jar (runnable) files) & I do not know how to import and run these successfully.

I am not sure how to share the files here and there is too much code to copy & paste directly, but I've tried using the import feature by right clicking on my project, then importing:
Project > import > general > file system > choosing the folder & files > finish

But I can't find the imported files & probably did that completely wrong. I'm not sure.

This is a SnapShop project. I am importing: SnapShopConfiguration.java, SnapShop.java, Runnable_jar_7a.jar, PixelImage.java, Pixel.java, FlipHorizontalFilter.java, Filter.java, and a .png file.

Comment: Not really a programming question. You should start by perusing https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nav/1 .

Comment: _File > Open Projects from File System..._